# What are the oldest Anglican hymns

Tags: music, hymns

I am interested in the oldest Anglican hymns that are still in use either in the [1940](https://archive.org/details/hymnalofprotesta0000prot/page/n5/mode/2up) or the [1982 Episcopal hymnals](https://archive.org/details/hymnal1982accord00epis/page/n3/mode/2up).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: I must observe that the world-wide Anglican church uses other hymnals than the ones you are citing, which makes the question ambiguous. I myself grew up on the "English Hymnal", which includes mediaeval hymns. "O come all ye faithful" is a translation of ADESTE FIDELES.

Comment: I cannot find the 1942 Episcopal hymnal, I think you meant 1940.  Availability is also confirmed by [*Wikipedia* list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English-language_hymnals_by_denomination#Anglican).

Comment: There are several metric psalms such as O God our help in Ages Past and The Lord's My Shepherd. Would they count?

Answer (score 0):

I'll get us started. The hymn called "[Saint Patrick's Breastplate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Patrick%27s_Breastplate)" ("I bind unto myself today the strong name of the Trinity") was written in 1889, not that long ago, but the lyrics are based on an 11th Century prayer.